# How to do Unit Test with Jest and Enzyme against a React component where there are API calls in its useEffect function

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme, okta

New to Jest and Enzyme. I'm not sure how to plan unit test for this case:

I have a component named "Monitor.jsx". It's a functional component. And it has the following features:

1. There's a state: `const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);`
2. There's a `useEffect` function.
3. Within that `useEffect` function, there are two API calls.
4. Those two API calls are done via "axios", and in front of each axios instance, there is an interceptor.
5. In my webapp, I use "Okta" for authorization and authentication. So every time user logs in, and switch around pages, there can be identity checks, like in "Monitor.jsx": `const { authState, authService } = useOktaAuth();` . And I need to pass token and clientId from them along in my API call in the `useEffect` function:

   ```
   useEffect(() => {
       const payload = {
         headers: {
           access_token: authState.accessToken,
           client_id: authService._oktaAuth.options.clientId,
         },
       };
       (async () => {
         await getDataAPI(payload)
           .then((res) => {
           ...
   ```
6. When APIs are done, data are fetched and ready-to-be-rendered, I update state `isLoading` to false, meaning this component is done loading.
7. With loading "done", I then render the "real" elements and info on the screen by:

   ```
   return (authState.isAuthenticated && !isLoading) ? 
   <div className="monitor-list__cardContainer">
      [real content based on data from APIs] 
      ...
   </div> : <p>loading...</p>
   ```

So it seems a bit complicated to test them all at once (e.g. in Monitor.test.jsx), but they are indeed involved in the same component, "Monitor.jsx" though. And I'm struggling with how to plan my test, what are the procedures of doing an unit test for this component based on what I describe.

Please suggest, even some dummy code will be better.

Comment: why not export to a testable function and call that function from within useEffect ?

Comment: Are you trying to test that `getDataAPI` does what you expect? Or trying to test the entire effect in the component? What are you trying to test?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's that complicated: you just have to invoke the `useEffect` from your test (modify whatever is there as a dependency). Then what you want to test is just the API requests (I recommend `axios-mock-adapter`) and the presence / absence of the `<p>...loading</p>`.